# how i can get all class ( and inner classes ) from a psiFile? (intellij plugin)

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I am new in plugin development and i want to search the reference of all classes in a project and check if they extend a spesific class but with getClasses dont gives me the inner classes :

```
PsiJavaFile psiJavaFile = (PsiJavaFile) PsiManager.getInstance(project).findFile(virtualFile);
PsiClass[] javaFileClasses = psiJavaFile.getClasses();

for (PsiClass javaFileClass : javaFileClasses) {

    PsiReferenceList extendsList = javaFileClass.getExtendsList();
....to something with extendList...
}
```

How i can search for inner class in psiJavaFile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PsiClass` has [`getInnerClasses`](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/java/java-psi-api/src/com/intellij/psi/PsiClass.java#L167) and [`getAllInnterClasses`](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/java/java-psi-api/src/com/intellij/psi/PsiClass.java#L199) methods.

Comment: just saw it! sorry